# Semicolon in front of my numerical values

Tags: r, excel

I have problems getting rid of the ";" before my numbers. I assume its an issue with excel, but I am fairly new to the program, so I need help. Any advice would be deeply appreciated.

[image]

Comment: ? `read.csv2(...)`

Comment: You can view the data directly with any kind of text editor. If there really is a semicolon in front of all those values, you can write a script to 'sanitize' your data and strip out the unwanted characters, before you try to use it in R. I'm sure R has some features for this, but why work on broken data?

Comment: Is this a CSV file or an XLSX file? `df$Value <- as.numeric(sub(";","",as.character(df$Value)))` should help if you've already read it into R ...

Comment: Or just use the find/replace in the edit menu and find ";" and replace with ""

Comment: `read.table("yourfile.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")`

Answer (score 1):

Apply to each relevant column a function which replaces semicolon with the empty string and then converts to numeric.

```
# test data
DF <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = c(";3", ";4"), C = c(";6", ";7"))

DF[2:3] <- lapply(DF[2:3], function(x) as.numeric(sub(";", "", x)))
```

giving:

```
> DF
  A B C
1 1 3 6
2 2 4 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Within **Excel**

Select all the cells in the worksheet, pull-down the Find/Replace Dialog from the Ribbon, and remove all ***;***:

[image]